# Python access mother class fields

Tags: python, tree, iterator, instance

While writing an iterator for a tree class in python I stumbled upon the issue, that I apparently cannot access fields and methods of the mother class without instanciating an iterator instance with a reference to an already existing Tree instance, so I always need to call the iterator like "it.iterate(tree)" which is pretty ugly. I was wondering whether there was some way to design this stuff, so an instance reference for the iterator and its methods is not required. SO, can I somehow access the fields of an instance of Tree from an instance of the Iterator without passing a reference of the Tree instance to the iterator?

```
########################################################################
# basic tree class, can be traversed bottom up from right hand corner
########################################################################

import sys

########################################################################
########################################################################
class Node:
    """!
    @brief node class
    """
    def __init__(self, pred=-1, ID=0, label=None):

        self.sucs = list()
        self.pred = pred
        self.ID = ID
        self.suc_count = 0
        self.label = label
########################################################################
    def make_suc(self, ID, label=None):
        """!
        @brief generates new successor node, assigning it a unique ID
        """
        self.suc_count += 1
        sucID = ID+1
        suc = Node(self, sucID, label)
        self.sucs.append(suc)
        return suc
########################################################################
########################################################################
class Tree:
    """!
    @brief tree class
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()
        self.allNodes = dict() # mapping from IDs (strings) to nodes
        self.init()
        self.leaves = list()
########################################################################
    # initializes node dict
    def init(self):
        self.allNodes[0] = self.root
########################################################################
    def find_node(self, ID):
        """!
        @brief looks up a node's ID and returns the node itself
        """
        return self.allNodes[ID]
########################################################################
    def add(self, parent, label=None):
        """!
        @brief adds a new node under parent with label label
        """
        if parent != Node:
            parent = self.find_node(parent)
        suc = parent.make_suc(len(self.allNodes)-1, label)
        self.allNodes[suc.ID] = suc
########################################################################
    def traverse(self, node):
        """!
        @brief traverses tree
        """
        for suc in node.sucs:
            self.traverse(suc)
            print suc.label
########################################################################
    def get_leaves(self, node):
        """!
        @brief when called resets leveas field and build it up anew by
               traversing tree and adding all leaves to it
        """
        self.leaves = list()
        self._find_leaves(node)
        return self.leaves
########################################################################
    def get_dominated(self, node, dom_nodes=[]):
        """!
        @brief finds all dominated nodes
        """
        for suc in node.sucs:
            self.get_dominated(suc, dom_nodes)
            dom_nodes.append(suc)
########################################################################
    def _find_leaves(self, node):
        """!
        @brief traverses tree in in order and adds all leaves to leaves field
               last leaf in list will be right hand corner of tree, due to in
               order travsersal
        """
        if node.suc_count == 0:
            self.leaves.append(node)
        for suc in node.sucs:
            self._find_leaves(suc)
########################################################################
    class TreeRHCIterator:
        """!
        @brief Right hand corner initialised iterator, traverses tree bottom
               up, right to left
        """
        def __init__(self, tree):
            self.current = tree.get_leaves(tree.root)[-1] # last leaf is right corner
            self.csi = len(self.current.sucs)-1 # right most index of sucs
            self.visited = list() # visisted nodes
########################################################################
        def begin(self, tree):
            return tree.get_leaves(tree.root)[-1]
########################################################################
        def end(self, tree):
            return tree.root
########################################################################
        def find_unvisited(self, node, tree):
            """!
            @brief finds rightmost unvisited node transitively dominated by node
            """
            leaves = tree.get_leaves(tree.root)
            # loop through leaves from right to left, as leaves are listed
            # in order, thus rightmost list elememt is rightmost leaf
            for i in range(len(leaves)-1, -1, -1):
                # return the first leaf, that has not been visited yet
                if leaves[i] not in self.visited:
                    return leaves[i]
            # return None if all leaves have been visited
            return None
########################################################################
        def go_up(self, node, tree):
            """!
            @brief sets self.current to pred of self.current,
                   appends current node to visited nodes, reassignes csi
            """
            self.visited.append(self.current)
            self.current = self.current.pred
            if self.current.sucs[0] not in self.visited:
                self.current = self.find_unvisited(self.current, tree)
            self.csi = len(self.current.sucs)-1
            self.visited.append(self.current)
########################################################################
        def iterate(self, tree):
            """!
            @brief advances iterator
            """
            # if current node is a leaf, go to its predecessor
            if self.current.suc_count == 0 or self.current in self.visited:
                self.go_up(self.current, tree)
            # if current node is not a leaf, find the next unvisited
            else:
                self.current = self.find_unvisited(self.current, tree)
########################################################################
########################################################################
```

called like this:

```
tree = Tree()

it = tree.TreeRHCIterator(tree)
end = it.end(tree)

while (it.current != end):
    print it.current.label
    it.iterate(tree)
```

## Edit

After implementing the standard iterator protocol I am a little confused about its workings. Somehow the start node is being skipped when looping over the tree. SO I made a test class to study the behavior, and there no element is being skipped, even though the iteration method basically works the same way. Could somebody shed some light on this for me?

Redesigned iterator:

```
########################################################################
# RIGHT-HAND-CORNER-BOTTOM-UP-POST-ORDER-TRAVERSAL-ITERATOR
########################################################################
    class RBPIter:
        """!
        @brief Right hand corner initialised iterator, traverses tree bottom
                     up, right to left
        """
        def __init__(self, tree):
            self.current = tree.get_leaves(tree.root)[-1] # last leaf is right corner
            self.csi = len(self.current.sucs)-1 # right most index of sucs
            self.visited = list() # visisted nodes
            self.tree = tree
            self.label = self.current.label
########################################################################
        def __iter__(self):
            print "iter: ", self.label
            return self
########################################################################
        def begin(self):
            return self.tree.get_leaves(self.tree.root)[-1]
########################################################################
        def end(self):
            return self.tree.root
########################################################################
        def find_unvisited(self, node):
            """!
            @brief finds rightmost unvisited node transitively dominated by node
            """
            leaves = self.tree.get_leaves(self.tree.root)
            # loop through leaves from right to left, as leaves are listed
            # in order, thus rightmost list elememt is rightmost leaf
            for i in range(len(leaves)-1, -1, -1):
                # return the first leaf, that has not been visited yet
                if leaves[i] not in self.visited:
                    self.label = leaves[i].label
                    return leaves[i]
            # return None if all leaves have been visited
            return None
########################################################################
        def go_up(self, node):
            """!
            @brief sets self.current to pred of self.current,
                         appends current node to visited nodes, reassignes csi
            """
            self.visited.append(self.current)
            self.current = self.current.pred
            if self.current.sucs[0] not in self.visited:
                self.current = self.find_unvisited(self.current)
            self.label = self.current.label
            self.csi = len(self.current.sucs)-1
            self.visited.append(self.current)
########################################################################
        def next(self):
            """!
            @brief advances iterator
            """
            print "next: ", self.label
            # if current node is a leaf, go to its predecessor
            if self.current.suc_count == 0 or self.current in self.visited:
                self.go_up(self.current)
            # if current node is not a leaf, find the next unvisited
            else:
                self.current = self.find_unvisited(self.current)
            if self.current == self.end():
                raise StopIteration
            return self
########################################################################
########################################################################
```

For the following test file I get the the following output:

```
tree1 = Tree()

tree1.add(0, "t")
tree1.add(1, "e")
tree1.add(2, "s")
tree1.add(3, "t")

tree1.add(2, "t")
tree1.add(5, "r")
tree1.add(6, "i")
tree1.add(7, "s")

tree1.add(6, "a")

for node in tree1.RBPIter(tree1):
  print node.label
```

output:

```
iter:  a
next:  a
s
next:  s
i
next:  i
r
next:  r
t
next:  t
t
next:  t
s
next:  s
e
next:  e
t
next:  t
```

The tree to this looks like this:

! [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFDZL.png) [a trie]

So, as you see, the "a" - meaning the right hand corner node is missing, and I don't understand why, because the iterator method returns the first element correctly, as you can see in the debug output.

Comment: Why are you not using common iterator protocol? Implementing `__iter__`?

Comment: Didn't know about that before. But also, I might want to have different iterators for different traversal orders.

Comment: For this problem, why don't you store the `tree` object in the `__init__`, with `self.tree = tree`?

Comment: Good idea. Completely missed that :D But what about the more general question, apart from this specific one?

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complex for a tree implementation in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an iterator look nice with something like this:

```
class TreeIter:
    def __init__(self, parametersIfAny):
        code godes here
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
       code that makes the iteration

class Tree:
    def __iter__(self):
        return TreeIter(parametersIfAny)
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
tree = Tree()

for node in tree:
    print node.label
```

If you need to have many different iterators, i.e. inorder, postorder, etc. I had to do something like this last year (albeit with graphs). What i did then was something like:

```
class PostOrderIter:
    def __init__(self, tree):
        self.tree = tree #and some more stuff
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
class PostOrder:
    def __init__(self, tree):
        self.tree = tree #and some more stuff
    def __iter__(self):
        return PostOrderIter(self.tree)
```

to invoke it with:

```
for node in PostOrder(tree):
    print node.label
```

Comment: I see, thanks. But I guess you cannot specify different iterators? For example one for in order traversal one for post order etc.? Or in case of say lists one for forward and one for backward iterating?

Edit: Got ninjaed by edit